# Why is it "mir ist übel" and not "ich bin übel"?

Tags: grammar, personal-pronoun, reflexive

To express we feel nauseous we may say

> Mir ist übel. Mir ist schlecht. Mir ist schwindlig.

What are the grammatical rules behind this? Why don't we say *"Ich bin übel"* when we say

> Ich bin benommen. Ich bin müde. Ich bin froh. Ich bin dumm.

and *"mir ist..."* is not used in the latter cases?

Comment: *schwindlig*? Wer sagt sowas in dem Kontext? Die Schwaben?

Comment: @Em1: meine Oma sagte das immer.

Comment: Du kannst aber doch sagen: *Ich bin übel(wollend)*

Comment: in Österreich ist "mir ist schwindlig" üblich

Comment: @Em1 wenn es denn so ist sage ich sowas auch^^

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Feelings/emotions are expressed here with the Dativ (*mir ist*), not with Nominativ (*ich bin*).

You could argue, that this is done for differentiation purposes, because (as [Matthias](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3820/161) mentioned) "Mir ist übel" and "Ich bin übel" mean different things. But that does not explain other uses like:

> Mir ist, als hätte es geklopft. (I think someone knocked at the door.)

You are expressing a feeling, you are uncertain if really someone knocked. An "Ich bin" construction does not exist here.

<sup>For further readings (and if you want to lobotomize yourself) I recommend "[Die Kodierung von Emotionen in Texten](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GRsFDtczL6YJ:related.springerprotocols.com/lp/de-gruyter/die-kodierung-von-emotionen-in-texten-teil-1-grundlagen-i07s5Mwq5N%20grammatik%20%22mir%20ist%20schlecht%22%20%22ich%20bin%20schlecht%22&cd=16&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=firefox-a)".</sup>

One possible explanation how this evolved is the shortening of sentences. Let us take as example:

> Es ist mir kalt. (It's cold here for me.)

Now we have a typical sentence with a dative object. It could be that the object was transferred to the subject to shorten the sentence, because people are lazy (sprechfaul). Then we get:

> Mir ist kalt. (I am cold.)

But this is guesswork. I have no reference to back this up.

Comment: Your explanation is correct. "Mir" is not a word that can do the action. Some textbooks call this construct an "understood" or implied subject. The "es" is implied or understood to be there.

Answer (score 3):

The word "mir" is in this case a [reflexive pronoun](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflexivpronomen).

Em1 already stated that "übel" can have different meanings.

- Without a reflexive pronoun ("Ich bin übel") you would say that you are vicious (not very common).
- With a reflexive pronoun ("Mir ist übel") you say that you are feeling sick.

I am *not sure* why a reflexive pronoun is used. Possibly to

- clarify the meaning
- describe a feeling instead of a person's condition

Comment: Ist der Unterschied nicht, dass das eine einen *Zustand* beschreibt, während das andere ein *Gefühl* oder *Empfinden*. Es gibt gute Beispiele: *Ich bin langweilig - Mir ist langweilig.* // *Ich bin kalt - Mir ist kalt* (Achtung, regional auch *Ich hab kalt*)

Comment: @Em1 Das klingt einleuchtend. Ich finde leider keine Belege dafür. Aber meine Antwort werde ich ergänzen. Danke!

Comment: Ist nur Bauchgefühl, ob es stimmt, weiß ich nicht. Vllt gibt es auch Beispiele, die meine Vermutung widerlegen...

Comment: This is a very old answer, but it's not too late to point out that "mir" is **not** a reflexive pronoun here. It's just a dative object. A reflexive pronoun "reflects" the  subject of the sentence, like in "ich langweile mich".