Can "übel" have a positive meaning?
I have heard the following in the movie "Spieleabend":

Hatte ich schon auf mehreren Festivals dabei, bringt immer übelst Fun, und ist ganz gut , um sich kennenzulernen.

Context: a guy is talking about a game he is giving to a friend for a game night with the girl he's going out and her friends.
I thought "übel" meant "bad", but it seems to have a positive connotation here. I can't find it in DWDS or Word Reference. I suppose it is slang? Is it usual in informal language?

Also be aware of another (negative) meaning of übel: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3817/why-is-it-mir-ist-%C3%BCbel-and-not-ich-bin-%C3%BCbel

Does positive by perspective count - "Wir haben dem Gegner übel mitgespielt" (We did the enemy/opponent bad)?

It's noughties (2000-2010, see ngram) teenage slang and means "very". See https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/übelst. It is widely understood, but it is marked as slang, so you would not find it in formal contexts.

It seems to be usual in many languages to use words that mean something bad for something good or as an intensifier in slang, e.g. "sick" and "fuc*ing" in English. So confusing for foreigners!

It might be worth mentioning that only superlative übelst is used that way, while positive übel is not.

@JonathanHerrera Well, no. "Übel gut" is just as fine.

@tofro Interesting. While I am very familiar with übelst, "we" would have never used übel that way.

It seems youth wants to ruin the language. Once I heard a young girl meeting another say "Hey Alter!"; I mean the other person was neither old nor male...

I would locate that predominantly in East Germany, together with "verkeimt".

@U.Windl language cant be ruined. If people use it people understand it and as such it fulfills the only purpose language has.

As someone who was a teenager in the noughties in south-west germany, both "übel gut" and "übelst gut" sound normal to me.

@AlanEvangelista I would like to (nitpicky, tongue-in-cheek) note that "fuc#ing" actually means something (if consensual) very good - it's seen (especially in the US) as a "bad word", but it doesn't really "mean something bad" ;)

It's going off-topic, but in Bavarian language "sau" (pig) can have the meaning of "sehr" (very), so a seemingly negative word might not be negative at all, like in "saugut" or or "Hunger wie d' Sau haben".

I was an exchange student in Dresden in 2004 and hardly an adjective was ever used that was not preceded by "übelst!"

@Syndic "Fuc*ing" is an intensifier in English (i.e. you can say "she's a fuc*ing bitch" or "she's fuc*ing awesome"), it doesn't imply something good. "sick" was my example of word that means something bad and can be used for something good.

Just to add and referring to the title question, that
the negation „nicht übel“ has a positive connotation,
i.e., it exceeds neutrality, in that something turns
(surprisingly) out to be better than initially expected.
This parallels the English "not bad", and similarly the
French «C'est pas mal.»

Please don't misuse answers for comments. There might be a reason, you have to earn some reputation to be allowed to comment, but it is not to make you use answers for comment. Aside from this, "nicht übel" wäre das Äquivalent zu "not bad", nicht "übelst".

This was my first thought but of course, "übel" here is still "bad" because its negation is good.

Fair enough, dear unknown @userunknown ; I would locate it at the threshold between comment and answer. Aside from this, you appear to confirm the equivalence of
„nicht übel“,  "not bad", and «pas mal», all sharing a sort of favour, thank you.
